# Keyboard and mouse in SDL2 app without X11 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sdl-2

I'm working on SDL2 application. Now I try to run it on Raspberry PI (Zero W) with Raspbian Stretch Lite installed, without X11.

I built and installed SDL2 from source like described [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/22/raspberry-pi-raspbian-getting-started-sdl-2/).

Used these configuration flags:

```
./configure \
--disable-pulseaudio \
--disable-esd \
--disable-video-mir \
--disable-video-wayland \
--disable-video-x11 \
--host=arm-raspberry-linux-gnueabihf \
```

Now I able to compile and run my app. It shows main screen in fullscreen mode properly.

But it can't receive any keyboard or mouse events which expected.

I assume that I missed something in SDL2 build configuration.
How to enable mouse and keyboard in app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular users are usually prohibited from reading the `/dev/input/*` files directly by default, which is what SDL does when run on a raw Linux framebuffer console.

From [the SDL docs (`README-raspberrypi.md`)](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/3c6a6dad3487/docs/README-raspberrypi.md):

```
================================================================================
 No input
================================================================================

Make sure you belong to the "input" group.

    sudo usermod -aG input `whoami`
```

Or run your program as root.

Comment: With the above, on my system, mouse is not moving in SDL2 application, while it is working correctly in SDL application. Keyboard is working in both. What should be done?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by appending a group as @genpfault told and by installing `libudev-dev` then rebuilt SDL.

Comment: Could you clarify the `udev` bit? Neither the packaged version in Ubuntu Fossa, the version i compiled on that system or the 1.2 version in Xenial list libudev.so in the NEED section when using objdump - yet my app works just fine in linux Ubuntu x86/64 but not on Raspberry OS armhf. Must i cross-compile for armhf to enable udev specifically? Shouldn't the packaged version suffice?